# Any explanation as to why Output Stream only prints the last line of the translated variable to a new file instead of all the lines?

Tags: java, file, apache-pig, new-operator, outputstream

I am trying to convert English words from a text file to a new file that translates the words into pig Latin. Everything translates the way it should when it is simply printed to the console but the issue I am having is that only the last line from the initial file appears on the new one.

```
public static void newFile(String pigLatin) {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/amie/Documents/inputnewnew.pig.txt"));
        os.write(pigLatin.getBytes(), 0, pigLatin.length());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `FileOutputStream` is overriding  the existing file. What you need to do is to use another constructor with `append` parameter

```
FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)
```

like

```
os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/...", true))
```

Take a look at the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)